# Is it possible to stent a dissecting Type A aortic-aneurysm?

Tags: aneurysm

I would like to understand if there is precedence for stenting an Ascending Aortic dissection / pseudo-aneurysm.  An example of a dissection / pseudo aneurysm is provided

I think that this NIH article indicates it may be possible?

https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27881689/

The problem is that is that it would be nice to have a larger population?

[image]

Comment: You asked about ascending aortic aneurysm repair before. What did you learn? A requirement of this site is that you show evidence of prior research, e.g. a quote with a link to the source. A depiction is not evidence of research (sorry). If you want to advocate and ask the doctor a question, what if they ask where you got your information? "Online" is not a popular reply. "This article by YYY et. al. states..." is a *much* better reply! The first will be dismissed, the latter will be addressed.

Comment: @anongoodnurse. Thank you for commenting.   It would be ideal if there was a study, though I would be pleased to hear anecdotal encouragement / success stories

Comment: If you get anecdotal replies they will most likely be deleted.

Comment: Anecdotes are fairly unhelpful. If, say, someone has survived a surgical procedure that usually results in 99% mortality, *for that one person*, it was 100% survival. You need to look at the numbers, and for that, you need to look at studies.

Comment: Agreed.  A proper sample size is necessary to draw a conclusion with any stochastic confidence